# Need the difference between two columns ' different in number of items ' in two different tables in MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I need the difference between items i bought and items i sold, items i bought in this table

```
  ID   |ItemName| PriceOfUnit  | NumberOfItems I bought |DateIBought| 
  1    |  tea   |       3      |            6           |15/11/2015 |
  2    | coffee |       5      |            4           |16/11/2015 |
  3    |  tea   |       4      |            10          |20/12/2015 |
  4    | juice  |       5      |            15          | 1/1/2016  |
  5    | coffee |       3      |            5           | 15/3/2016 |
  6    | water  |       5      |            2           | 16/4/2016 |
```

and items I sold is in this table

```
  ID   |ItemName| PriceOfUnit  | NumberOfItems I sold   |DateIBought| 
  1    | coffee |       5      |            6           |  1/1/2016 |
  2    |  tea   |       5      |            9           | 15/3/2016 |
  3    | coffee |       4      |            2           | 20/4/2016 |
  4    | juice  |       5      |            11          |  1/1/2016 |
```

I need a query , SQL query OR union Query in MS Access to get this result  ?

```
  ID   |ItemName| NumberOfItems I have   |
  1    | coffee |            1           |
  2    |  tea   |            7           |
  3    | juice  |            4           |
  4    |  water |            2           |
```

How can I get this result ?
Where `NumberOfItems I have =  NumberOfItems I bought - NumberOfItems I sold`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide attribute names or table names and you spec'd two RDBMS products, so here is p-code for your solution:

q1:
SELECT ItemName, SUM(bought) as SumBought from tBought GROUP BY ItemName

q2:
SELECT ItemName, SUM(sold) as SumSold from tSold GROUP BY ItemName

q3:
SELECT q1.ItemName, (SumBought - SumSold) as difference from q1 inner join q2 on q1.ItemName = q2.ItemName

Comment: nicomp
great thank you,
i need if there's no sold item , show me number i bought from this item

Comment: if i didn't sold item , it isn't displayed
as my example it doesn't display " water "